# iOS5 Push notifications, Are there any alternatives to the Notification Center?

Tags: push-notification, ios5, nsnotificationcenter

I have 2 related questions regarding the new push notification in iOS5:

1. If my application is not running in the background - Can the notification arrive to my application silently?
2. Can I revert back to the old modal popup UI for push notification? Can I do it programmatically only for my application notification while leaving all the rest using the notification center disappearing notification?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a silent message by not providing the sound property with the push message.

You cannot revert back to the old modal popup.

Comment: but in that case - my app won't receive the notification - it will arrive to the iphone os - and will get displayed on the top bar (in the new stile)

Comment: ... Your app will receive the notification from the os when the app is open. There is a function for that. Your app does not handle the notifications. the OS handles them.
I was wrong to say that you cannot revert back to old style. it is in the settings for notifications on the phone. But there is no developer access to that.